# Keep select value on change with laravel

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am having a paginated backend table with db-data. The admin person can filter that table for data status. This happens via ajax. Everything works fine but I do not get the selected filter value to remain selected when I click on the second pagination link.

E.g. I choose select option: '1' => 'Active' so that only db-rows show up that have a status of 1. But when I then click on the second pagination link to see the next 20 rows then again it also displays the inactive db-rows. How would I get the selected option to remain selected in this situation? I tried Input::old('status') and passing $selected to view as below but no success. Thank you for any hint!

View:

```
<form id="filter_form" onsubmit="" action="<?php echo URL::action('countries@anyIndex'); ?>">
    <?php echo Form::select('filter_status', funcs::get_status_options(), $selected, array('id' => 'filter_status')); ?>
</form>
```

Ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $("#filter_status").on('change', function(){
        frm = $("#filter_form");
        frm.serialize();
        status = $('#filter_status').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(frm).attr('action'),
            data: {status: status},
            success: function(data){
                $("#list").html(data.list);
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
class countries extends BaseController {

    public $filter = array(0,1,2);

    function anyIndex()
    {
        $data['title'] = "Countries list";
        if(Input::has('status')){
            $status = Input::get('status');
            if($status != 2){
                $this->filter = array($status);
            }
        }
        $d['items'] = $this->_getItems(20);

        if(Request::ajax()){
            $data['list'] = View::make('admin/countries/countries_list', $d)->withInput($status)->render();
            return Response::json($data);
        }

        $data['selected'] = $this->filter;
        $data['list'] = View::make('admin/countries/countries_list', $d);  
        return View::make('admin/admin_layout')->nest('view', 'admin/countries/countries_view', $data);
    }

    private function _getItems($paginate)
    {
        $items = Country::whereIn('status', $this->filter)->paginate($paginate);
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a Session for this?

Comment: Thanks for that! yes thats right I just did that and in fact the option now remains selected but still all db-rows show up when I click the next pagination link. I need to sleep over it maybe I know tomorrow what I am doing wrong. cheers

Comment: Yeah session is the solution. Thank you very much!